# Spring Security custom filter exemption

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a spring security which have config like this.

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless"
        entry-point-ref="loginAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <security:custom-filter ref="preAuthFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/product/test/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>       


</security:http>
```

My preAuthFilter filters all request and throws an error message if xml that recieved is malformed, but I want to have an exemption. For example I want to add another `<security:intercept-url />` that has its own `custom-filter`. 
 Or is it possible to have a another entry point for authentication? then I will just add my custom-filter.
 
How can achieve this? Any ideas?  
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `security:http` tag without pattern attribute defaults to *all* requests. You can add another `security:http` with a `pattern` attribute pointing to the specific url pattern and declare it above the `security:http` you already have as more specific one is supposed to be declared first. There you can configure the filters again for the specific url. [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) first checks the incoming url with that of pattern declared in `security:http`. If it does not matches it bypasses rest of the configuration inside that `security:http` and moves to the next `security:http` effectively the one *without* the `pattern` attribute.

Comment: so before my spring-security above I need to declare another security:http with a pattern attribute? I get it. I don't know about the pattern attribute in security:http. I need to read more about spring-security. Thank you.